# sys module giving different output when running Python script through IDLE and by double-clicking the script

Tags: python, python-2.7, undefined-behavior

I was trying to get the Python directory for executing some scripts there. I found an odd behavior.

**This is just a sample code for pointing out the specific problem**. I will place this path into a variable for further use.

I placed this code in a script

```
import sys
print sys.executable[: - len('pythonw.exe')]
raw_input()
```

The output is this when I run it through IDLE

```
C:\Python27\
```

The output is this when I run it by double clicking the script

```
C:\Python27
```

I don't understand what is going on here. Why the different formats? It should be consistent or am I missing something?

Comment: when you click it it is probably running through `python.exe` so you are removing the extra char from the w

Comment: @JoranBeasley Is there a way to check that in Python?

Comment: @AseemBansal: Why don't you just print `sys.executable` instead of trimming it, and then you'll see what it actually is?

Comment: @BrenBarn I know without printing where the python.exe is present. I am writing a script in which I needed to get that directory path into a variable. I want to be OS independent so I don't want to hardcode it. The code I have placed in this question is just a sample to point out the problem that occurred.

Comment: you should use the method in my answer to get the dir name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
```

is what you should use.

When you click it it is probably running through python.exe so you are removing the extra char from the w.